# convert pdf to image with imageMagick

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, popen

Any Idea what I am doing wrong here? The convert never seems to even open the pdf:

```
a = r"\\server\gis\agsResources\resources\map4.pdf"
b = r"\\server\gis\agsResources\resources\map4.png"
boutput = Popen([
    r'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16\convert.exe',
   '-density=400',
   '-scale=2000x1000',
   '-sOutputFile=%s' % (b),
    '%s' %(a),

],stdout=PIPE,stderr = STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Indent your code 4 spaces (or use the curly brackets in editor after highlighting all your code) so that it's readable.  Breaking the Popen call at commas will help readability too.

Comment: Do you have read/write access to the share `\\server\gis\` ?  Do you have the same problem if you try this with local files instead of remote files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option syntax does not look right. When I try your code (with just paths changed), **convert: unrecognized option '-density=400'** is written to the `boutput` variable.

This works for me:

```
boutput = Popen([
    '/bin/convert',
    '-density', '400',
    '-scale', '2000x1000',
    '%s' % a,
    '%s' % b 
], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT).communicate()[0]
```